# Required in HTML form not working

Tags: javascript, html

I know, there are a ton of questions on stack about required.  I have tried many options with no result.

```
<script>
  // Javascript function called by "submit" button handler,
  // to show results.
  function updateOutput(resultHtml) {
    toggle_visibility('inProgress');
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = resultHtml;
  }

  // From blog.movalog.com/a/javascript-toggle-visibility/
  function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
    else
      e.style.display = 'block';
  }


</script>

<div id="formDiv" >
<!-- Form div will be hidden after form submission -->
<form id="myForm" > 

   name : <input name="name" type="text" required /> <br/>
   Eadres: <input name="email" type="text" required /><br/>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit"   
      onclick="toggle_visibility('formDiv'); toggle_visibility('inProgress');
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
          .processForm(this.parentNode)"  />
</form>
</div>

<div id="inProgress" style="display: none;">
<!-- Progress starts hidden, but will be shown after form submission. -->
Balabla
</div>


<div id="output">
  <!-- Blank div will be filled with "Thanks.html" after form submission. -->
</div>
```

When I use `submitform()` like this

```
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" 
      onclick="toggle_visibility('formDiv');  toggle_visibility('inProgress');submitform();
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
          .processForm(this.parentNode)"  />
```

this part is not running properly

Way is required not working? And is there solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Don't use an `onclick` handler on your `submit` button. Use an `onsubmit` handler on your `form` tag.

The `onclick` handler won't get fired anyway if I use enter to submit the form.

Browsers won't fire `onsubmit` if the form isn't validated according to it's input validation attributes (like `required`), and the form isn't marked `novalidate`.

Comment: If I use onclick the form is triggered. When I use onsubmit, the problem remains.

Comment: @Adam `onsubmit` goes on the `form` tag, not the `input` button.